# Why doesnt DELETE based on SELECT work with mysql 5.0

Tags: mysql, sql

Using Mysql 5.0 this works

```
select * 
from jforum_topics t1 
where topic_id in ( 
            select topic_id 
            from jforum_posts t2  
            where need_moderate=true
        );
```

but this doesn't

```
mysql> delete from jforum_topics t1 
        where topic_id in ( 
                select topic_id 
                from jforum_posts t2  
                where need_moderate=true
            );
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where topic_id in ( select topic_id from jforum_posts t2  where need_moderate=tr' at line 1

I thought it should work , how else do i do this ?

Comment: Are you saying that the query does not work when run from the terminal using the mysql shell, but it does from some other mechaism of running queries like phpMyAdmin or similiar

Comment: `delete t1 from jforum_topics t1 ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `in` or `exists` **without aliasing** (in this case `t1`) :

```
delete from jforum_topics 
      where topic_id in ( 
                select topic_id 
                  from jforum_posts t2  
                 where need_moderate=true
                );
```

or

```
delete from jforum_topics 
      where exists ( 
                select 0
                  from jforum_posts t2  
                 where need_moderate=true
                   and t2.topic_id = jforum_topics.topic_id
                );
```

or need to alias **twice** :

```
delete t1 from jforum_topics t1 
      where topic_id in ( 
                select topic_id 
                  from jforum_posts t2  
                 where need_moderate=true
                );
```

Comment: you're welcome @PaulTaylor . MySQL is interesting from this point of view.